# Vmware virtual machines slow down drastically over time

Tags: virtual-machine, performance, vmware, lag

The vm os is latest Windows 10. Over time while my pc is inactive but there is always a automation running on the virtual machines, the vm slow down alot to the point where the cursor looks laggy af and automation takes over 40 seconds more to run from start to end. I disabled memory page trimming, enabled hyper-v on host and tried absolutely everything yet it still happens. I use latest vmware version. How can i fix it?
So far my only solution is rebooting the vms, which is not reliable...

Edit: A note, the vm is a clone of one vm to save space

Comment: I have a Windows 10 Host 19043.1023 (21H1) with VMware Workstation 16.1.2. Three machines: i Windows 2 Linux. This setup is running 7x24 and the machines do not slow down.  Weekly restarts. See how much memory is being used overall and whether the macro running is chewing up memory. That is the most likely situation.

Comment: Well i checked, it doesn't but the ram contents are often written to paging file despite free memory.. The usage always stays around 60-70%

Comment: I will look around a bit. Check what the macro does. If your host has a hard drive, does the macro make excessive use of disk. That can also drag down a virtual machine (any machine).

Comment: You might have a memory leak in the VM which eats up the RAM and overflows into the disk. Once RAM access becomes disk access, performance is nil.

Comment: Same in my ubuntu 20 machine over a win 10 host. Didn't find any memory leak in my code. In my case when running the code over a native ubuntu 20 everything is fine. I believe VM is the cause